# How to get ROWID when inserting into table using FORALL and RETURNING

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to get ROWID of inserted record using RETURNING clause from FORALL INSERT statement (bulk insert) back into pl/sql table of records (associative array of records).
I believe, that problem is in using table of records in FORALL and BULK COLLECT together.

See the example:

```
CREATE TABLE test2 (num NUMBER);
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
  TYPE r_rec IS RECORD (num NUMBER, row_id ROWID);
--  TYPE t_rid IS TABLE OF rowid INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF r_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  v_tab     t_tab;
  --v_rid     t_rid;
BEGIN
  v_tab(1).num := 1.11;
  v_tab(2).num := 2.22;
  v_tab(3).num := 3.33;
  --
  FORALL i IN v_tab.first..v_tab.last
    INSERT INTO test2 (num)
    VALUES (v_tab(i).num)
    RETURNING rowid BULK COLLECT INTO v_tab(i).row_id
  ;
  FOR i IN v_tab.first..v_tab.last
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('num/rowid : ' || v_tab(i).num || '/' || v_tab(i).row_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

It raises error: **PLS-00437: FORALL bulk index cannot be used in RETURNING clause**
Where is a problem here? Do I need another PL/SQL table for returning ROWIDs?

Comment: Well, rowid is assigned to a record when that record is being inserted. It is possible to get it in RETURNING clause. I only need to get it back into pl/sql table+record. See the example. My questions are in context of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need another PL/SQL table for returning ROWIDs?

**Yes** ..You can try it as below: You would need an another collection to hold the return of rowids since "FORALL bulk index cannot be used in RETURNING clause"

```
DECLARE
  TYPE r_rec IS RECORD (num NUMBER, row_id ROWID);

  TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF r_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  v_tab     t_tab;

  TYPE r_rw IS TABLE OF ROWID index by pls_integer;

  v_rw r_rw;

BEGIN
  v_tab(1).num := 1.11;

  v_tab(2).num := 2.22;

  v_tab(3).num := 3.33;

  --
  FORALL i IN v_tab.first..v_tab.last
    INSERT INTO test2 (num)
    VALUES (v_tab(i).num)
    RETURNING rowid BULK COLLECT INTO v_rw;

  FOR i IN v_tab.first..v_tab.last
  LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line('num/rowid : ' || v_tab(i).num || '/' ||v_rw(i));
  END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this is a bit fragile solution, since it is not ensured that index of  `v_rw` is the same thing as index of `v_tab`. But it looks like only possible solution.

Comment: @LiborStefek. This is running in the loop of `v_tab` hence you can be sure that the index used is correct. Refer this http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_dml.htm . Also if this answered you query you can close the question by accepting the solution.

Comment: Try to change `v_tab(1).num := 1.11;` to `v_tab(4).num := 1.11;`. Indices `i` are 2,3,4, but indices of `v_rw` will be 1,2,3. This is what I mean by "fragile". I would need to take it into account.

Comment: And what would be the value for `v_tab(1).num` then ? You wanted to make sparse collection or what ? It would then throw error.

Comment: `Indices i are 2,3,4,` - No Oracle consider `FORALL i` index not your collection index. Also, when you do such thing it would throw error. Try out.

Comment: There is no need to start with `1`. It is associative array. But yes, I usually have it starting at `1`. Only sometimes at `0`. :-)

Comment: @LiborStefek . I mean i never said you have to start with 1. You can start with 0 as well provided you dont make the collection sparse.